# How to generate users activity log in loopback

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

Is there any possible way to generate a log of user activities in loopback?

Comment: You can create or use an express middleware.

Comment: Dear @AndrewFerk thanks for guiding, Actually I don't know much about Expressjs but i am used middleware  in Loopback for a few purposes.

Comment: It looks likes express middleware is not the way to track user activity in loopback. Loopback [issue 3286](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/3286) specifically says the current context cannot be accessed in middleware.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a [boot script](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Defining-boot-scripts.html) and use a [strong-remoting hook](https://github.com/strongloop/strong-remoting#hooks) to log all user activity.

**server/boot/activity-log.js**

```js
// Log logged in user's API requests
module.exports = (app) => {
  app.remotes().before('**', async (ctx) => {
    const { accessToken } = ctx.req;

    // ignore unauthenticated requests
    if (!accessToken) return;

    const user = await accessToken.user.get();
    console.log(`${user.email} => ${ctx.req.url}`);
  });
};
```